# Adjust bluetooth adapter transmit power

Tags: bluetooth

I attached a bluetooth adapter to my RPi in order to create an iBeacon.
This works as intended.

What's important to me is the "Beacon Region Entered" event. In order to influence this, I thought it best to reduce the transmitting power of the adapter but I am just not able to find out how (if even possible [via the console]) to do this!
Any input would be appreciated!

**Hardware:**

- RPi B+
- LogiLink BT0015 USB bluetooth V4.0 EDR Class1 Micro, CSR Chip

  - Device's "user friendly" name = **CSR8510 A10**

**Software:**

- Raspbian Jessie
- BlueZ

**`bccmd pslist` dump:**

```
0x0001 - Bluetooth address (8 bytes)
0x00f2 - Disable the HCI Command_Status event on boot (2 bytes)
0x0108 - Local device's "user friendly" name (12 bytes)
0x0209 - TX and RX PIO control (2 bytes)
0x0229 - Deep sleep state usage (2 bytes)
0x0246 - External clock request enable (2 bytes)
0x025c - Module security code (10 bytes)
0x025d - VM disable (2 bytes)
0x0263 - Module manufactuer data 5 (40 bytes)
0x028c - User configuration data 2 (2 bytes)
0x02b0 - User configuration data 38 (10 bytes)
0x02c2 - USB product string (22 bytes)
0x02c5 - USB attributes bitmap (2 bytes)
0x02c6 - USB device maximum power consumption (2 bytes)
0x02da - Unknown (4 bytes)
0x02db - Unknown (16 bytes)
0x03be - I2C configuration (2 bytes)
0x04b0 - Unknown (6 bytes)
0x04b1 - Unknown (4 bytes)
0x04b8 - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x04b9 - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x04ba - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x04f8 - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x04f9 - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x2131 - Unknown (50 bytes)
0x2132 - Unknown (22 bytes)
0x21f0 - Unknown (2 bytes)
0x220a - Unknown (98 bytes)
0x2225 - Unknown (40 bytes)
0x222b - Unknown (78 bytes)
0x2578 - Unknown (2 bytes)
```

Comment: Did you ever get any more information on how to reduce the transmit power on the BT0015? I emailed Logilink for some examples but have not received any response.

I'd like to decrease the transmit power to just a few meters as well.

Comment: @roqvist No, unfortunately I have not found anything on the topic. I sort of got it under "control" in a hacky way by placing a metal plate in front of it in the direction I wanted to dampen it. But obviously that's not really a controlled way to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to control the region by reducing the power (which I believe is not at all easy, if it's even possible), I suggest you monitor the signal strength instead. For example:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47466 [bluetooth](/questions/tagged/bluetooth)